# How to hide CSS background images that use !important

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that will hide images on any page I'm currently viewing. It works for removing `<img>` tags and it creates a CSS style that tries to hide all background images. The issue I keep encountering are background images that are specified with `!important`. I can't figure out how to hide them.

Here is a codepen demonstrating the issue: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/kbDcv

If you remove the `!important` from the background image then it all works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: hide the backgrounded divs exactly like you do the images: var imgs2=document.querySelectorAll("div[style*='background']");

Comment: [Works great](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/kbDcv). Thanks dandavis. If you include that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide divs with backgrounds in the same manner as you do img tags in the linked code:

```
var imgs=document.querySelectorAll("div[style*='background']");
for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
   imgs[i].style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

Comment: This is especially fine since it's a bookmarklet and **I** will always be using a modern browser and `querySelectorAll` should always work :)

Comment: Note, this will not find divs with background-images defined through a CSS class.

Comment: @Malk: that's true, but the OP doesn't need that capability and it would likely require tons of CPU-heavy dom iteration and property sniffing that would best be avoided if not required. it would also be impossible to sniff backgrounds defined in CSS served off-site, which limits the practicality and universality of such an approach.

Comment: I wouldn't say OP doesn't need it. Background-image is usually defined in a style sheet after all, and "any page" is mentioned. You are right that it is a heavy script needing to call `getComputedStyle` for every element, but it's really dependant on just OPs machine so that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your CSS occurs after that CSS on the page and put the `!important` override on your CSS. Also, since you specify that you are using JavaScript, you can add your CSS as inline CSS on the actual element and use `!important`. The only thing that overrides inline important is <strike>user agent</strike> user important style sheets.<sup>[[reference]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-CSS21-20030915/cascade.html#cascade)[[example]](http://www.nimbustier.net/publications/web/user-css.html.en)</sup>

Comment: How do I identify which element has the inline style? Or do I just need to iterate over the entire DOM? (which I suspect could be very expensive)

Comment: @AlexFord: see my comment on your question for the answer to that without massive iteration

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you can use the newer (IE9+) `querySelectorAll` function:

```
function hideImages() {
  var d = document,s = window.getComputedStyle;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    d.querySelectorAll("body *"),
    function(el){
      if (s(el).backgroundImage.match(/url/) || 
         el.tagName === 'IMG'){
          el.style.visibility="hidden";
      }
    }
  );
}

$('button').click(hideImages);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rBnIx

Updated to include background-images set via CSS.

---

Though, you could probably lose a lot by turning anything with a background-image invisible. You might have better luck just turning that property off. You could either check the computed style of each element like above or just set them all like below. The function below uses `setProperty` to override `!important` which is also IE9+.

```
function hideImages() {
  var a=document.querySelectorAll("body *"),i=a.length;
  function _f(n){
         if (n.tagName === 'IMG') n.style.visibility="hidden";
         n.style.setProperty("background-image", "none", "important");
  };
  while(--i) _f(a[i]);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tnrdH